# Magento 2 Payment Module Sample

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, github

Wanted to check the sample module for online payments from Magento, but noticed that the module is not anymore in Magento Github Repository.

Does anyone have any idea where can it be found?

[image]

[Broken Link to Github from official documentation](https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-module-payment-gateway)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official repo of Magento don't have the modules anymore, but I noticed that Mageplaza has a clone of the repositories.

Anyone interested can access the example modules in this link.

[magento2-samples](https://github.com/mageplaza/magento2-samples)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that entire repository was removed, so no more sample apps. Instead I believe they want you to refer to the dev docs as well as existing modules in the code base.

Specifically for payment gateways you’d be looking at Braintree as your example implementation in code and the [Payment gateway integration](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/payments-integrations/bk-payments-integrations.html) documentation page.

Comment: Yes i know about the official documentation but was interested in the demo modules from Magento. Anyway i found a repo from mageplaza that had the code. Thank you :)

Comment: The problem of the example modules is that they haven’t been updated and they don’t follow current best practices. Just keep this in mind as you look at them.

Comment: I want to check on them more as starting point